# Ember findBelongsTo

Tags: ember.js, model, store

How to use findBelongsto? 
So my notes model is related to a contact model (1- many relationship where contact is on the LHS).
I need to get all of notes data based on the contact ID. I am fetching this data from a 3rd party API where the related data is fetched in this format: some_url/Contacts/:contactID/link/notes
I need to fetch the notes data in the model hook. Can I do it with findBelongsTo like this: findBelongsTo('contact', contactID, 'notes')?

contact model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  assigned_user_name: DS.attr('string'),
  password_c: DS.attr('string'),
  account_name: DS.attr('string'),
  department: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  phone_work: DS.attr('string'),
  primary_address_street: DS.attr('string'),
  primary_address_city: DS.attr('string'),
  primary_address_state: DS.attr('string'),
  primary_address_country: DS.attr('string'),
  twitter: DS.attr('string'),

  notes: DS.hasMany('note')
});
```

note model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    contact: DS.belongsTo('contact'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Update: So I implemented findBelongsTo('contact', contactID, 'notes') and it threw up the follwoing error:                                                                                                                      Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined

Comment: You should show the response from the API in your question if you're using findBelongsTo. Also which Adapter implementation are you using (RestAdapter, JSONApiAdapter etc.)?

Comment: Rest adapter. No response from the network because of the error so basically the request doesn't even go :/

Comment: What does the response from the contact endpoint look like?

Comment: Also what version of Ember are you using?

Comment: version 2.7. Contact end point as in the response from the contact model hook? Because I am trying to implement this relationship thing in the notes model hook and no request is going through because it cannot find my contact model name :/

Comment: As in what is the payload coming back from your API for the contact model. The RESTAdapter expects it to contain an array of links. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findBelongsTo

Comment: Yes exactly like the link you sent and my links is also there with the url /Contacts/:contactID/link/notes